# Change TD border color with HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a little trouble with changing one `tr` border color
My table is something like this

```
<table>
    <div id="one">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

I would like first `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` to be white and the second one to be blue

I have tried with

```
#one td, #one tr,#onetable{
border: 1px solid white;  
border-color:#ff0000;
```

But it didn't work

Comment: yikes a div between a table and a tr is not valid HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670424/border-around-specific-rows-in-a-table

Comment: also why are you specifying border color as white in one line and red in next? Was that some trial?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    #one td {
        border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr id="one">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="two">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #one td {
        border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr id="one">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="two">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VCA9Q/

Answer (score 5):

Here you go

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {background-color: beige;}
    table {border-collapse: separate;}
    table td { width: 50px; height: 50px;}
    table tr:first-child td {border: 1px solid #fff; }
    table tr:last-child td {border: 1px solid #0000FF; }
</style>
</head>
<body>    
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[and a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFcG2/4/)

(btw `#0000FF` is blue)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to zebra-stripe your table:

```
table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    border-color: #fff;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    border-color: #00f;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CX8Yg/).

Note that, if you want two cells in the first row, and three in the second, you should use the `colspan` attribute in your HTML (on either the first, or, as in the demo below, the second `td` element):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CX8Yg/).

References:

- [`:nth-child()` browser-compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t55).
- [CSS `:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
table{
    background:#000;
}

tr#one{
    background:blue;
}

tr#two{
    background:red;
}

tr td{
    background: inherit;
}
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr id='one'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='two'>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```