# Using a "stand alone" "display: table-cell;" on a div works; but is this allowed?

Tags: html, css

***edit***: edit made because of comments:

I asked, because I can't find a doc about, where is what `display:xxxx;` allowed.

I asked, because I can "feel" that a rendering engine can "understand" what it means to be a rectangle be rendered like a `table-cell` not like a `block`, even without a `table-row` around

but I am not sure ...

I do not ask for workaround like scripting (I do not mind, its just not the question)

---

***original:***

I am still confused about some display properties values (ie. the table ones);

I want (need) a table (or table like construct), that allows me to style the "row". The problem is, that the data to display, is in fact calling for a HTML `<table>` (means: I have no controll of the text inside the cells, like in an invoice, ist not just formating static data)

I can (could)  solve my prob like shown in the code snipped below, if i just replace the table things like that (a short cut, I hope its clear what I mean)

```
table
  tr
    td 
    td
    td 
  tr
    td 
    td
    td
```

with

```
div
  div
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
  div
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
```

Just tell the inner `DIV` to display as/like `table-cell` makes them same hight, and `vertical-align` does like cell should, and all is fine

so again the question: But is this allowed, altough it works?

what confuses me is, that if I do what I often read (here) i should make it like that:

```
div **display:table**
  div **display:table-row**
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
  div **display:table-row**
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
    div display:table-cell;
```

but that is the same like table, tr, td (how I would expect), so why should I use it?

on the other hand (I did not try that so far) what happens to

```
table
  tr **display:inline-block**
    td 
    td
    td 
  tr **display:inline-block**
    td 
    td
    td
```

```css
.no-table {
  display:inline-block;
  display:inline-table;
  border:3px solid brown;
  padding:3px;

}

.no-row {
  display:block; 
  /* display:table-row; */
  border:3px solid blue;
  padding:3px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}


  
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  border:3px solid green;
  width:40px;
  max-width:40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class='no-table'>
  <div class='no-row'>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
    <div class='cell'>texttexttext</div>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
  </div>
  <div class='no-row'>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
    <div class='cell'>text text</div>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
  </div>
  <div class='no-row'>
    <div class='cell'>text text text</div>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
    <div class='cell'>text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once again the question(s): is the use of a "stand alone or out of context" display: somthing allowed? And if it behaves like expected, will it work tomorrow, too?

Comment: Your second code block is legal I think (`table-cell` can be applied to a div but it always needs to be surrounded by a `table-row` element etc.) but why do it in the first place? That stuff is insane. Just use a `<table>`.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I need a background image behind the row (not the cells)

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/670498/187606) helps? I've never tried it myself but it looks promising.

Comment: @Pekka웃 where can I find the documentation that says a `table-cell` needs to be surrounded by `table-row`?

Comment: @Huangism you're right, there doesn't seem to be such a requirement. I always thought there was. The specs seem to say (on superficial reading) that the client must generate any missing elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

Comment: However, if you make a div behave like a `tr` chances are it will become as un-stylable as the `tr` element itself.

Comment: I think it will validate but sometimes it doesn't work that well unless it is in the 'table' structure

Comment: @Pekka웃: there is no element missing. all are here, the questionwas a (not html part) css display: something - like display:none isnt missing for HTML

Comment: @Huangism: thats - more ore less - my question, "allowed or not allowed, thats the question!" in modern html theater

Comment: @halfbit if by allow you mean validates in the validator then yes it validates. Personally, I usually put the `table-cells` inside of a `table`

Comment: @Huangism: sure it does!  html != css, ttry <tr style='background:url(my_friends_foto)'>, it will validate, but look at browsers behaviour

Comment: @halfbit ok I am not sure what you meant by the last comment but basically, if it works for you then do what you gotta do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that it is "tolerated"

[w3c standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display/#layout_specific-leaf-types)

> **layout-specific leaf types**
>
> These display types require their parent to be of a particular display
>   type, but can accept any display-inside value. For example, a
>   table-caption box must have a table parent, but can establish any kind
>   of formatting context for its children.
>
> Boxes with layout-specific types generate wrapper boxes around
>   themselves when placed in an incompatible parent, as defined by their
>   respective specifications.

So, in the first paragraph, it is specified that they **must** have a table parent.

But in the second paragraph, it is said that if you don't do that, the browser will fill it automatically. So, somehow, you could say that it is *allowed*

Comment: I would give an extra +1 for finding then 'doc-needle in the doc-haystack', at least I now know that it is named 'layout_specific-leaf-types'