# Apply style to specific child table placed in another table

Tags: html, css, asp.net, wizard

I am in a need to apply a style to the table which is placed in the third row of another table,

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>HTML Table</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="wizard-ux">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>test Table 2</td>
              <td>test Table 2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>test Table 2</td>
              <td>test Table 2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Save (Width has to be 90%)</td>
                <td>Cancel (Width has to be 10%)</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

since this is asp.net wizard I don't have id or class for the child table, the only reference is "wizard-ux" of the parent. I need to set the width of the first column as 90% and second column as 10% through CSS,

can somebody suggest a CSS for this,

thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you use `nth:child(x)`?

Comment: try `table.wizard-ux tr:last-of-type table`

Comment: .wizard-ux:nth-last-child(2) td:first-child { width:90%; text-align:right;}
.wizard-ux:nth-last-child(2) td:nth-child(2) { width:10%; text-align:center;}

but fails

Comment: arun kumar, tried table.wizard-ux tr:last-of-type table td {width:90%;} but no effect

Comment: try `table.wizard-ux tr:nth-child(3) tr td:nth-child(1) { width: 90%; } table.wizard-ux tr:nth-child(3) tr td:nth-child(2) { width: 10%; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border around specific rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670424/border-around-specific-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: Thank you Ravikumar, i am not seeing any nested tables in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below CSS

```
.wizard-ux tr:last-of-type table td:first-of-type
{
    width:90%;

}
.wizard-ux tr:last-of-type table td:last-of-type 
{
    width:10%;

}
```

Comment: Your comment above suggesting `table.wizard-ux tr:last-of-type table` was good enough. The problem is that the original HTML is invalid. Some of the inner tables do not have parent `td` tags, the tables are being placed directly in `tr` tags which is invalid.

Comment: Yes, it seems like he is using the tables under td as he is using under last tr but pasted the wrong html in question

Comment: i have created that for reference, but the case is those tables are getting auto generated by Asp.Net wizard, i need to align Save, Cancel buttons, anyways it works perfectly thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by giving id to those columns

```
<td id="wid90">Save</td>
<td id="win10">Cancel</td>
```

Then I use this css

```
#wid90 {
            width: 90%
        }
#wid10 {
            width: 10%
        }
```

I dont know if it works or not